# Error while trying to password protect .htaccess file

Tags: apache

Just for testing purpose I am trying my .htaccess file to be password protected on localhost.
I generated a .htpasswd file using  online tool which I placed at following location

My .htaccess file is located at-->

```
wamp/www/magentocustmod/.htaccess
```

With following content-->

```
AuthName "Restricted Area" 
AuthType Basic 
AuthUserFile /mypass/.htpasswd
require valid-use
```

But when I run  localhost/magentocustmod, I get a popup asking for password and user name after giving the correct user name
and password following message comes

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, admin@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log

Comment: *More information about this error may be available in the server error log* … so what does the server error log say?

Comment: @Quentin I found this in apache_error.log                                        "[Fri Mar 15 17:52:08 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (OS 3)The system cannot find the path specified.  : Could not open password file: D:/mypass/.htpasswd"

Comment: Have you created a .htpasswd file? Did you put it in that location?

Comment: @Quentin Y file location is "D:\wamp\www\mypass"

Comment: D:/mypass/.htpasswd is not the same as D:/wamp/www/mypass

Comment: @Quentin after placing the file at D:/wamp/www/mypass "[Fri Mar 15 18:00:58 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (OS 2)The system cannot find the file specified.  : Could not open password file: D:/wamp/www/mypass/.htpasswd"  this error comes to error log.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally it worked for me
The code in .htaccess file was as following.

```
AuthName "Restricted Area" 
AuthType Basic 
AuthUserFile /wamp/www/mypass/.htpasswd    
require valid-user
```

While saving file please remember to save the files properly otherwise these will be saved as .htaccess.txt and .htpasswd.txt.

Thanks